# SQL query that fries the server

Tags: mysql

I'm  having a really weird issue that burns my MySQL server. From my point of view (which is surely wrong), the query is pretty trivial.

I have a table to store PBX events and I try to get the last events for every agent to see his/her situation whenever my application is restarted or whatever.

Whenever I launch, the server goes up to 99% of CPU and lasts about 5 minutes to solve by itself.

It seems that's because the number of records, more than 100,000.

The table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eventos_centralita` (
  `idEvent` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fechaHora` datetime NOT NULL,
  `codAgente` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evento` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEvent`),
  KEY `codAgente` (`codAgente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=105847 ;
```

And the query is as follows:

```
SELECT a.* FROM eventos_centralita a 
LEFT JOIN eventos_centralita b ON b.codAgente = a.codAgente AND b.fechaHora > a.fechaHora 
GROUP BY a.codAgente
```

I've tried to limit it by date but no luck as the query doesn't give me anything. How could I improve the query to avoid this ?

Comment: Why is a left join necessary here? I would have expected something like SELECT codAgente, max(fechaHora) FROM eventos_centralita GROUP BY codAgente limit 0,20;

Comment: @jamie0726 you seem to be right but this is not giving correct results either... The hour seems to be right, but the event isn't... what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below:

```
SELECT a.* FROM eventos_centralita a 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT idEvent, MAX(fechaHora)
    FROM eventos_centralita  
    GROUP BY codAgente
) as b
ON a.idEvent = b.idEvent
```

Comment: Hi Minesh, this doesn't seems to be giving me correct results. For example, `120 2012-09-04 10:10:28 1022 116 Available` but, executing this: `SELECT * 
FROM eventos_centralita
WHERE codAgente =  '1009'
ORDER BY  eventos_centralita.fechaHora DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30`

Shows me this: `105894 2013-02-25 09:26:47 1022 112 Resting`

Comment: @AntonioLaguna If you are looking for latest result, can you try the above solution with MAX() function instead of MIN()

Comment: Sure, it seems that's a problem with MySQL with a bug in my server version.